# IIS10 url rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a simple question which is driving me crazy from the last week: I splitted a big application in "Default Web Site" into single applications grouped by directory so everyone could have his own git repository. So the main root directory is quite empty, just few scripts linked from outasides statically.
All the user point to the root directory, and I would like redirect this pointing to the stable application in /subdir_stable and not showing the user this action. Every application in subfolders have an own prefix beginning from his local and works in every subfolder I put.
So I need two type of action:
- users point to myhostname.local
- action1: get redirect to myhostname.local/subdir_stable
- action2: keep having their urls as myhostname.local

I have achieved the action1 using the url rewrite with this web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="/spot_backend">
                    <add key="/" value="/spot_backend" />
                </rewriteMap>
                <rewriteMap name="/">
                    <add key="/" value="/spot_backend" />
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for /">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{/:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I don't how to achieve the action2. Any hints?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't understand your requirement clearly. As far as I know, if you use the Rewrite to rewrite the url, it will not modify the url, that means if user use myhostname.local it will still keep the myhostname.local in the browser url.

Comment: Trying to be clearer: I have my pool of application: myhostname.local/app1 myhostname.local/app2 myhostname.local/app3. Well, myhostname.local is empty, when browser point myhostname.local I would like serve app1 as default. They can always point directly app2 or app3 as they like but default is app1. More, I would like user don't see this redirection and when they point myhostname.local they resolve myhostname.local/app1 but they see myhostname.local. Does url rewrite achieve this behavior?